# TypeScript: This expression is not callable. No constituent of type 'ExportValue' is callable. WebAssembly module

Tags: javascript, typescript, webassembly, deno

I got this problem when I run this code in index.ts with Deno.

```
const wasm = await Deno.readFile("./wasm_test/pkg/wasm_test_bg.wasm");
const wasmModule = new WebAssembly.Module(wasm);
const wasmInstance = new WebAssembly.Instance(wasmModule);
const wasmTest = wasmInstance.exports;
wasmTest.sum(1, 3); // Error
```

> Error: This expression is not callable. No constituent of type 'ExportValue' is callable.

I get and error when calling `sum`,  it should give me a 4 as a result.
When I run it as index.js it works perfectly.
I used wasm-pack to compile the Rust code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the name `add` is not known.
Change the 4th line of your code as below:

```js
const wasm = await Deno.readFile("./add.wasm");
const wasmModule = new WebAssembly.Module(wasm);
const wasmInstance = new WebAssembly.Instance(wasmModule);
const sum = wasmInstance.exports.sum as CallableFunction; // exports.add if you test with the below linked wasm.
console.log(sum(1, 3))
```

See [documentation](https://deno.land/manual@v1.28.1/runtime/webassembly/using_wasm).

For my test I found a wasm example with an `add`-function [here](https://stisa.space/articles/webassembly-basic-example-adding/).